# depending on the max aggregate function to count the same column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to get the date of the latest game and the number of game a player had in a 1 hour window before that.

Here is the code I want to execute

```
SELECT MAX(saved_date), COUNT(saved_date) FROM Game
WHERE username = 'user_name'
HAVING saved_date >= MAX(saved_date) - interval '1' hour;
```

but it gives me the error `not a GROUP BY expression`. The error doesn't appear when I add the line `GROUP BY saved_date` but it doesn't answer my first question. I know I can do it in two statements but I'd prefer it done in one.

Do you have any advice or solution ? As this is my first post here, please be indulgent, thanks !

Additional info :

The `Game` table is created like this :

```
CREATE TABLE GAME (
    game_id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    ...
    saved_date DATE,
    ...
);
```

output with `GROUP BY saved_date` :

```
MAX(saved_date) | COUNT(saved_date)
----------------|------------------
 29/03/21       | 1
 29/03/21       | 1 
 29/03/21       | 1
```

desired output :

```
MAX(saved_date) | COUNT(saved_date)
----------------|------------------
 29/03/21       | 3
```

Comment: You have tagged Oracle 11g; however, the `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` syntax was not supported until Oracle 12. Which version are you using?

Comment: Are you really sure about the results for `GROUP BY saved_date` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use analytic functions (instead of aggregation functions):

```sql
SELECT saved_date,
       COUNT(*) OVER (
         ORDER BY saved_date DESC
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '0' HOUR PRECEDING
               AND     INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING
       ) AS num_games
FROM   game
WHERE  username = 'user_name'
ORDER BY saved_date DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

or, if you are using Oracle 11g:

```sql
SELECT saved_date,
       num_games
FROM   (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY saved_date DESC ) AS rn,
         saved_date,
         COUNT(*) OVER (
           ORDER BY saved_date DESC
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '0' HOUR PRECEDING
                 AND     INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING
         ) AS num_games
  FROM   game
  WHERE  username = 'user_name'
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE GAME (
    game_id    NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    username   VARCHAR2(100),
    saved_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO game ( username, saved_date )
SELECT 'user_name', DATE '1970-01-01' + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> SAVED_DATE          | NUM_GAMES
> :------------------ | --------:
> 1970-01-01 03:10:00 |         7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3fea58d0a8058c361118b180baf0b669)*

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery.  I would approach this using a window function:

```
SELECT MAX(saved_date), COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT G.*,
             MAX(G.saved_date) OVER (PARTITION BY G.username) as max_saved_date
      FROM Game G
      WHERE G.username = 'user_name'
     ) G
WHERE saved_date >= max_saved_date - interval '1' hour;
```